# Google cast Remote Display Presentation is being immediately dismissed

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I've tested a few of the sample apps that use the Google Cast remote display API. They all have the same issue:

I can connect to chromecast fine.
Then I get a Blank screen (and no sound).

In Android studio, my only hint is the following message:

Presentation is being immediately dismissed because the display metrics have changed since it was created.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the [Presentation.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/99766cf40ed706aad36032f2107fb0c1e54fc398/core/java/android/app/Presentation.java) file, there's a comment that says "Since we were not watching for display changes until just now, there is a chance that the display metrics have changed.  If so, we will need to dismiss the presentation immediately.  This case is expected to be rare but surprising, so we'll write a log message about it."

Comment: Also, "If the display metrics have changed (for example, if the display has been resized or rotated), then the system automatically calls {@link #cancel} to dismiss the presentation."

Is there something in your device that's changing the display?

Comment: This may be off topic, but can you tell me why you have chosen Google Cast Remote API vs. classic Android SDK's `MediaRouter` + `Presentation` API ?

Comment: Remote uses MediaRouter and Presentation. Do you have an example of the 'classic' approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed at last! CM fixed it. All builds after 2016-03-15 are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out CM roms were the problem. Flashed Oxygen OS on the OneplusOne and it started working.

I fear that both Google and CM will play the blame game and never get this fixed. Bug filed with Google already went that way (they said, have CM fix this). Will file with CM, see what happens...

Comment: CM13 still has the bug :(